# Jenkins Build fails with error

Tags: android, git, jenkins, gradle

When i try to run a task in Jenkins to build my app from source codes (deployer from Git server) - build fails with the following output

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace
> /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url http://git.ias.su:8082/stekotin/tamway.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://git.ias.su:8082/stekotin/tamway.git
> /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
> /usr/bin/git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git4412605623925353709.credentials # timeout=10
> /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://git.ias.su:8082/stekotin/tamway.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5eb38d7ab1a8900308eb214b68f628cc7da539da (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 5eb38d7ab1a8900308eb214b68f628cc7da539da
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace/gradlew --stacktrace build clean
WARNING [Project: :app] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
:ActiveAndroid-master:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning

:ActiveAndroid-master:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:classes
:ActiveAndroid-master:jar
:ActiveAndroid-master:javadocs
:ActiveAndroid-master:javadocsJar
:ActiveAndroid-master:sourcesJar
:ActiveAndroid-master:signArchives SKIPPED
:ActiveAndroid-master:assemble
:ActiveAndroid-master:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:test UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:check UP-TO-DATE
:ActiveAndroid-master:build
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
:app:prepareMeGrantlandAutofittextview020Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:compileDebugJavaNote:      /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace/app/src/main/java/su/ias/amway/activities/BaseChooseActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources        
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:compileReleaseJavaNote:     /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace/app/src/main/java/su/ias/amway/activities/BaseChooseActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 :app:lintVitalRelease SKIPPED
 :app:compileReleaseNdk
 :app:preDexRelease
 :app:dexRelease
 :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
 :app:packageRelease
 :app:assembleRelease
 :app:assemble
 :app:compileLint
 :app:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 83 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 83 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace/app/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to    /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Amway/workspace/app/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
:app:check
:app:build
:ActiveAndroid-master:clean
:app:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3 mins 35.266 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:183)
at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.createItemNode(PreDexCache.java:59)
at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.saveItems(PreProcessCache.java:478)
at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache.clear(PreProcessCache.java:367)
at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreProcessCache$clear$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_configureProject_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:313)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:111)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to use different versions of gradle, building with a wrapper - and none helped. Ca

Comment: Any update on the solution?

Comment: The problem suddenly dissappeared after Jenkins update. Nothing to do with it anymore.